# Summing my HTML input text is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I need to sum four input text values, but nothing is working. Here is the code I am trying:

```js
<script>
    var uno    = document.getElementsByName('base')[0];
    var dos = document.getElementsByName('bonos')[0];
    var tres     = document.getElementsByName('salud')[0];
    var cuatro    = document.getElementsByName('afp')[0];
    var cinco   = document.getElementsByName('bruto')[0];

    function updateInput() {
        cinco.value = parseFloat(uno.value) + parseFloat(dos.value) + parseFloat(tres.value) + parseFloat(cuatro.value);
    }

    cinco.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
    cinco.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
</script>
```

The name of the input text are correct but the sum is not parsing. Any ideas?
The input `CINCO` must sum the values from uno, dos, tres and cuatro but it shows only `0`.

Comment: What is not working? Does the function get called? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Where have you placed your script tag?

Comment: The input that sum all values from uno, dos tres and cuatro (cinco) just show 0

Comment: Do the elements exist in the DOM when they are selected? Typically you would wait for the document to load first.

Comment: please trace in console the values for uno, duo, tres etc.

Comment: can you move all the variable definitions inside the function and check?

Comment: If cinco is the target, why wouldn't you attach the keyup/change handlers to the other inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the event binding to incorrect element, I suspect that your issue is with respect to execution of script. Try updating to

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var uno    = document.getElementsByName('base')[0];
    var dos = document.getElementsByName('bonos')[0];
    var tres     = document.getElementsByName('salud')[0];
    var cuatro    = document.getElementsByName('afp')[0];
    var cinco   = document.getElementsByName('bruto')[0];

    function updateInput() {
        cinco.value = parseFloat(uno.value) + parseFloat(dos.value) + parseFloat(tres.value) + parseFloat(cuatro.value);
    }

    // update event listeners here
    uno.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
    uno.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);

   // ... similarly add listeners for other elements as well.
};
</script>
```

**Note** : I will suggest you to bind the `updateInput` function in `onchange` and `onkeyup` in markup

e.g.

```
<input type="text" onchange="updateInput()" onkeyup="updateInput" name="base"/>
```

Comment: This answer worked fine, thanks a lot you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

This works regardless of whether the fields are blank or the input is not a number and triggers the sum after entry into any of the 4 inputs.

```
var uno = document.getElementsByName('base')[0];
var dos = document.getElementsByName('bonos')[0];
var tres = document.getElementsByName('salud')[0];
var cuatro = document.getElementsByName('afp')[0];
var cinco = document.getElementsByName('bruto')[0];

function getInputVal(inVal){
    return isNaN(parseFloat(inVal)) ? 0 : parseFloat(inVal);
}

function updateInput() {

    var unoVal = getInputVal(uno.value),
        dosVal = getInputVal(dos.value),
        tresVal = getInputVal(tres.value),
        cuatroVal = getInputVal(cuatro.value);

    cinco.value = unoVal + dosVal + tresVal + cuatroVal;
}

uno.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
dos.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
tres.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
cuatro.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bm6f97zs/1/